# Can't get php to update mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP script that I use to update a MySQL database that works fine how I'm using it, I am now using that same script to try to update another database table but I can't get it to write any updates to the table. The script doesn't display any errors, it just moves through the entire process as if it works but posts noting to MySQL. Like I said before, I already use this script with another form and it works perfect. All I have done with the new form is change the variables to match what I have and changed the database table name. All my punctuation is correct as well. I just can't figure out why it wont write the updated info to MySQL.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
//----------FORM DATA-----------//
$id=$_POST['id'];

$team_name=!empty($_POST['team_name'])? $_POST['team_name'] : '';
$first_name=!empty($_POST['first_name'])? $_POST['first_name'] : '';
$last_name=!empty($_POST['last_name'])? $_POST['last_name'] : '';
$registration=!empty($_POST['registration'])? $_POST['registration'] : '';
$pay_status=!empty($_POST['pay_status'])? $_POST['pay_status'] : '';
$physical=!empty($_POST['physical'])? $_POST['physical'] : '';
$photo=!empty($_POST['photo'])? $_POST['photo'] : '';
$notes=!empty($_POST['notes'])? $_POST['notes'] : '';


//----------CONNECT TO DATABASE----------//
include 'elite_connect.php';


mysql_query("UPDATE cheer SET  team_name='$team_name', first_name='$first_name', last_name='$last_name', registration='$registration', pay_status='$pay_status', physical='$physical', photo='$photo', notes='$notes'
WHERE `id` = '$id'");

mysql_affected_rows();

echo mysql_error();

?>
<html>
<body style="background-color: #C7DFDF">
<center>
<br><br><br>
<form name="results" method="post" action="cheer_results.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="cheerresult">
<input type="submit" class="submit" id="cheerresult" style="width: 165px" value="View Results">
</form>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm very aware of possible sql injection with this so please don't comment about it, I really don't care about it in this scenario!

Comment: Check what $_POST contains.Use var_dump($_POST) or print_r($_POST)

Comment: 1- wrap all of your php code in `if(isset($_POST['id'])){ .... }`, as this will check to see if your form was posted. 2- I don't see any elements in your form. So where are these values being posted from?

Comment: echo mysql_affected_rows();//this will return number of affected rows if it print nothing then your query doesn't meet the criteria to update any record.

Comment: `mysql_query($qry) or die(mysql_error());`.

Comment: @Deepu using print_r($_POST) I get the following 0Array ( [first_name] => Test [last_name] => Member [team_name] => LONGHORNS [registration] => YES [pay_status] => PENDING [pyshical] => YES [notes] => TEST NOTES [submit] => Update Member )  I see the misspelled physical and corrected that

Comment: mysql_* functions are depricated, use mysqli or PDE

Comment: Where is `[id]` in your `print_r($_POST)`? If that did not post, your update will not happen.

Comment: do you get an error or warning?

Comment: I think you are missing `<input name="id" value="#" />` in the form that is posting to this page.

Comment: no error no warning all I get is what I just posted above to Deepu

Comment: @Sean would that be a hidden field?

Comment: It could be, but a hidden field would still be in your `print_r($_POST)` data. If it is `disabled` it would not be in `$_POST`. So it could be `<input name="id" value="#" type="hidden" />` but not `<input name="id" value="#" type="hidden" disabled />`

Comment: @Sean I added a id field as you show and here is the print_r($_POST) 0Array ( [id] => # [first_name] => Test [last_name] => Member [team_name] => LONGHORNS [registration] => YES [pay_status] => PENDING [physical] => YES [notes] => TEST [submit] => Update Member )

Comment: That is almost there. I put in the `#` to represent a integer. You need to populate it with a value that is in your table.

Comment: @Sean I got it I added value=<?php echo $data2['id']?> in the id field and now it works. Thanks Sean if you post your solution as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any time you are using `$_POST` it is always a good idea to check if it is set using `isset()`

```
<?php
//----------FORM DATA-----------//

if(isset($_POST['id'])){

   $id=$_POST['id'];

   $team_name=!empty($_POST['team_name'])? $_POST['team_name'] : '';
   $first_name=!empty($_POST['first_name'])? $_POST['first_name'] : '';
   $last_name=!empty($_POST['last_name'])? $_POST['last_name'] : '';
   $registration=!empty($_POST['registration'])? $_POST['registration'] : '';
   $pay_status=!empty($_POST['pay_status'])? $_POST['pay_status'] : '';
   $physical=!empty($_POST['physical'])? $_POST['physical'] : '';
   $photo=!empty($_POST['photo'])? $_POST['photo'] : '';
   $notes=!empty($_POST['notes'])? $_POST['notes'] : '';


   //----------CONNECT TO DATABASE----------//
   include 'elite_connect.php';


   mysql_query("UPDATE cheer SET  team_name='$team_name', first_name='$first_name', last_name='$last_name', registration='$registration', pay_status='$pay_status', physical='$physical', photo='$photo', notes='$notes'
   WHERE `id` = '$id'");

   mysql_affected_rows();

   echo mysql_error();
}
?>
```

this way, if your code does not execute, you know that `id` was not posted. Which in this case can be easily resolved with adding the hidden input to your form.

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $data2['id']?>"  />
```

Comment: Your help is much appreciated Sean, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Im not clear but, can you try this base syntax once?

```
mysql_query("UPDATE cheer SET  team_name='".$team_name."', first_name='".$first_name."', last_name='".$last_name."', registration='".$registration."', pay_status='".$pay_status."', physical='".$physical."', photo='".$photo."', notes='".$notes."'
WHERE `id` = '".$id."'");
```

This worked for me many times!

Comment: php evaluates variables if placed in double quotes.

Comment: That does not matter - `The most important feature of double-quoted strings is the fact that variable names will be expanded.` http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double

Comment: just try like this also it works :
"UPDATE cheer SET  team_name='$team_name', first_name='$first_name', last_name='$last_name', registration='$registration', pay_status='$pay_status', physical='$physical', photo='$photo', notes='$notes'
WHERE `id` = '$id'"